# Details on Nginx access log parsing

Tags: nginx, graphite, rsyslog

**Need inputs:**

I'm planning to trend the http status codes `4xx, 5xx` and other non success status codes which is part of Nginx `access.log` in graphite. The continuous tailing of the `access.log` definitely hampers the nginx's performance since we are dealing with large traffic each min.

**What I tried so far:**

- I found https://github.com/mailru/graphite-nginx-module and tried compiling this module with my nginx, but it's not even throwing an error.
- My current plan is generating a parallel `access.log` using `rsyslog` in an another machine. And then deploying a log-tailer over there  to publish the HTTP status code counts to the graphite. But I would like to check with the community, is there a better way to deal this ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for well made question, but ”is there a better way to deal (with) this” sounds to me like ”too broad” question. I think you should instead ask about what you exactly want to achieve; I think there is million ways to optimize log policies, so we’d need to know precise thing you want to achieve instead. Also, if ”tailing” refers to ´tail -f foo´, it shouldn’t cause any real performance hit?

Comment: Hi, yes it does on a large scale systems ! tail -f, grep/awk and then publishing to graphite increases the request/response time by milliseconds. When we put this in production and start handling millions of requests it does.

Comment: Ah, well, in that big environments separate log servers should be given...